# I am having problems with responsive design on iPhone XR (maybe any iphone)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, responsive-design

So, I have this website: https://projeto-jogo-memoria.vercel.app/

I asked some friends to test it and one of them has an iPhone XR. According to the internet iPhone XR's screen width is 414 pixels.

If I open it on dev tools, it works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHH2x.png

But this is how it shows up on the phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq5Zx.jpg

I noticed the margin between circles is a lot bigger, but I don't know why this is happening. Could you guys help me?

EDIT ------
I noticed when the game is complete every (when every face is flipped) the margin works fine. On my code every button has an anchor tag like this:

```
<a id="card_${j}" class="card-round-container${(vals.includes(j) ? '' : ' ms-2' )} d-inline-block" onclick="proximoRound('#card_${j}')">
    <div class="card-round-back card-round-${tamanho_tabuleiro}x" onclick="">
        <i style="font-weight: bold;" class="d-none card-round-${tamanho_tabuleiro}x-icon fa-responsive-size-${tamanho_tabuleiro}x">${tabuleiro[j]}</i>
    </div>
</a>
```

When two cards with the same icon are flipped, I set type="" and onclick="" properties on the anchor and it seems to works fine. Maybe the bug is coming from the type="button" on the anchor?
EDIT -------

EDIT²:

This code is an example of the container, a row and a card.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="tabuleiro" class="row mb-3 mb-sm-4 mb-xl-3 mb-xll-5">
        <div class="mb-2 text-center col-12">
            <a id="card_0" class="card-round-container d-inline-block" type="button" onclick="proximoRound('#card_0')">
                 <div class="card-round-back card-round-4x" onclick>
                     <i style="font-weight: bold;" class="d-none card-round-4x-icon fa-responsive-size-4x">2</i>
                 </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SOLUTION: I removed type="button" from the anchor tag and the unecessary margin/padding seems to be removed. This seems to be some kind of problem with safari browser only. Does anyone know why it happened?

Comment: The code you have given seems to be of the set up page, not the game page. Please remove it and show just enough of the 4x4 game page to demonstrate the problem. Remember to include any relevant CSS. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

according to internet iphone XR screensize is `828x1792 pixels` and according to browser inspect tool the screensize of iphone XR is `414x896 pixels` and you r design changes below `260px` you need to do some css based on the `media quesries` .

You need to change the height and width of `.card-round-4x` if goes to below `260px`

Just change

```
@media (min-width: 0px)
.card-round-4x {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```